# Is it good to use ( $request->get('sth') ) instead of ( setting some parameters ) in controller function in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, parameters, request

Is it OK to use

```
$id = $request->get('some_id');
```

instead of setting some parameters in `Routes` AND `Controller` like:

```
Route::get('some_page/{parameters}', 'controllerName@functionName');
function functionName($parameters)
{
    $id = $parameters;
}
```

**Appreciation**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it's good. When you're using GET, both ways are similar and if you like to use `$request->get()` for some reason, it's totally ok.

If you're using Form, it's the only right way. Plus, you can create custom Request class to use it for validation and other operations:

https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#form-request-validation

Comment: Thank you so much dear @Alexey Mezenin :)

Answer (score 0):

They have two fundamentally different goals.

Using `$request->get()` is a way to retrieve a value from inside the php's REQUEST object regardless of its association with routing pattern you use.

Following HTTP's standards, you probably use `$_GET` to read some value without it changing the database [significantly] and you use `$_POST` to write data to you server.

While `{pattern}` in routing ONLY and ONLY should be used as a way for your application to locate something, some resource(s); in other words, its only goal is to help you route something in your server.

Nevertheless, in certain cases, such as /user/{id} the value of {id} might encounter some overlapping as to whether be treated as a route parameter or as a key of `$_REQUEST`.

Things such as tokens, filters criteria, sorting rules, referrers (when not significantly) etc. can be read right from `$_REQUEST` without interfering them into routing pattern of you application.

Comment: Thank you so much dear @Mostafa Talebi :)